# Can't find spaces in text with \s

Tags: replace

I want to delete all the spaces in a document so I tried this:

```
:s/\s//g
```

but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably worked only on the current line. You need to specify a range to the substitute command, for example:

```
:1,$s/\s//g
```

There is a shortcut for the range that matches the entire file, which is `%`:

```
:%s/\s//g
```

See `:help ranges`.